# Solving this recurrence relation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve an recurrence relation. I´ve tried a lot, but i couldn´t do it.
The ecuation is:
\begin{align}
T(n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \hspace{5mm} n=2 \\
2T( \lceil \frac{2n}{3} \rceil) + T(\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor
) + 2& \hspace{5mm} n > 2 \\
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}

I cant replace $n = 3^{k}$, because i need the exact solution for T(n).
Anyway, if i replace $n = 3^{k}$ i´m still stuck with the resolution.

Thanks

Comment: What is $T(1)$?

Comment: It seems weird that you would need an exact solution. Are you sure you need it? If so, how many different values of $T(n)$ did you compute before you gave up trying to find the pattern among them?